# Why is String equals not working in my code?

Tags: java, string, equals

I have already checked two compared strings, but even the value parameter str and temp is printed both "mn". The str.equals(temp) is still returning false.

```
public int strStr(String haystack, String needle) {
            StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer(needle);

            int result=-1;

            for(int i=0;i<=haystack.length()-needle.length();i++){
                StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer(haystack.substring(i, i+needle.length()));

                System.out.println(temp.equals(str));
                System.out.println(temp+"="+str);

                if (str.equals(temp)){
                    result=i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: `str.toString().equals...`

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing two `StringBuffer` objects.  The `equals(Object)` method for `StringBuffer` is inherited from `Object`, and is defined to be the same as comparing the object references.

The objects are different, and therefore, the result is `false` in your example.

Try this instead:

```
      if (str.toString().equals(temp.toString())){
```

This works because the `String.equals(Object)` compares the string values, not the string object references.  (But note that you have to convert both `StringBuffer` objects, because `String.equals(Object)` will always return false if the argument is not a `String` object.)

Note also that using `str` as the name for a `StringBuffer` variable is highly misleading.  Most people would expect something called `str` to be a `String`.  (I did!!)

---

FWIW, I was scratching my head for a more efficient way to compare the contents of two `StringBuffer` objects.  The above code creates and discards two temporary `String` objects.  The best I can come up with is to code it by hand; e.g. something like this:

```
    public boolean equalBuffers(StringBuffer sb1, StringBuffer sb2) {
        if (sb1 == sb2) {
            return true;
        }
        int len = sb1.length();
        if (len != sb2.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
             if (sb1.charAt(i) != sb2.charAt(i)) {
                  return false;
             }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: my situation is this: `str="sam_esp"` when using `if(str.equals("sam_esp"))` it returns false BUT when using `str.contains("esp")` it works. I'm 100% sure the string is correct i have tried so many times and printed `str` to make sure it's correct. Any ideas why `String.equals("")` doesn't work in my case?

Comment: Ask a new question., and be sure to include an MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the references to the StringBuffer objects rather than the actual strings.And

> StringBuffer class doesn't override the equals() method of Object class.

Try this

```
str.toString().equals(temp.toString())
```

> The java.lang.StringBuffer.toString() method returns a string representing the data in this sequence.
>
> A new String object is allocated and initialized to contain the character sequence currently represented by this object. This String is then returned.

thats why you can compare two StringBuffer object by converting them into string.

Comment: Khan, you might want to explain that `StringBuffer` (or `StringBuilder` for that matter) does not implement `equals()`, which means that `equals()` is the same as `==`.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing StringBuffer with String so the equals method always return false.

```
str.equals(temp.toString())
```

But you need to know another important concept here when you does

```
System.out.println(temp+"="+str);
```

you are printing temp which is stringbuilder, java internally calls temp.toString() to achieve this.

Comment: Both `str` and `temp` are `StringBuffer`.